# How to include fontawesome icons inside Bootstrap forms in WordPress (with CF7)?

Tags: html, wordpress, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, contact-form-7

I'm trying to make WordPress theme based on Bootstrap4. Everthing is going fine, but I stock with my contact form, which looks like this:


[image: Contact form]


Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST">
<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3 mt-5">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Imię i nazwisko" name="full_name">
</div>

<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
</div>

<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Treść wiadomości" rows="5" name="message"></textarea>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Wyślij wiadomość" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">
```

The problem is, I don't know how to transform this into a WordPress theme. I added Form in Contact Form 7, like this:

```
[text* your-name class:form-control class:mb-3 class:mt-5 placeholder "Imię i nazwisko"]
[email* your-email class:form-control class:mb-3 placeholder "Adres e-mail"]
[textarea your-message class:form-control class:mb-3 placeholder "Wiadomość"]
[submit class:btn class:btn-primary class:btn-block class:btn-lg "Wyślij"]
```

and `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="5" title="Formularz kontaktowy"]' ); ?>` in my index.html.

It works fine and even has some Bootstrap styles, but looks nothing like in the picture. Especially I don't know how to set the size of my fields and, more important, how to include this fancy little icons in them?
As a beginner, I will appreciate any advice that would help me solve my issue.

Comment: please try using the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-icons-and-labels/

Comment: I tried. Unfortunately when I apply classess for this I lose my Bootstrap styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html in your contact form 7 form editor.

Replace this code in Contact form 7 => **Form** text area.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3 mt-5">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    [text* your-name class:form-control class:mb-3 class:mt-5 placeholder "Imię i nazwisko"]
</div>

<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    [email* your-email class:form-control class:mb-3 placeholder "Adres e-mail"]
</div>

<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    [textarea your-message class:form-control class:mb-3 placeholder "Wiadomość"]
</div>

[submit class:btn class:btn-primary class:btn-block class:btn-lg "Wyślij"]
```

Comment: Yes, with this approach I was able to display icons next to my form fields and after some css styling even adjust the height of icons and fields to make them equal (which is great!), but I still have an issue... This looks exectly how I want only on normal screen, when I resizing it to be smaller icons moves above the form fields... I was trying to inlcude `display:inline` to `input-group`, but nothing has chaged... Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: check responsive design. I think your default CSS override the responsive CSS styles.